# how to fetch _id data in loopback

Tags: node.js, arangodb

My Database is arangodb. What i want to do is : I have data like this:

```
_id:authModel/1209597

 _key:1209597
{ 
   email: 'abc@gmail.com',
   password: 'password',
   subuser_ids:[ '811289', '1209611' ],
   id: '1209597' 
}
_id:authModel/811289
_key:811289
{ 
   email: 'pqr@gmail.com',
   password: 'password',
   id: '811289' 
}
```

actually i need to fetch data which is the ids in subuser_ids array, ie the subuser_ids contain 2 ids. I need to fetch the data that the subuser_id hold. suppose subuser_id is "811289" that is _id="811289" i need to fetch that data. am using arangodb and loopback. also i write an remote method to accesss that data. What i have is :

model.js

```
 var server = require("../../server/server");

module.exports = function (Authmodel) {
Authmodel.on("attached", function () {
    Authmodel.getApp(function (err, app) {
        Authmodel.getSubUsers = function (params, cb) {
            var result = [];

            params.forEach(function (id) {

                app.models.authModel.findOne({ "_id": id }, function (err, r) {
                    console.log("err", err);
                    console.log("r", r);
                    result.push(r);
                });
            })
            cb(null, result);
        };
    });
});

Authmodel.remoteMethod('getSubUsers', {
    accepts: { arg: 'params', type: 'array' },
    returns: { arg: 'result', type: 'array' }
});
```

};

i got the log in the result console but that data is not correct.

How can i solve this issue? i need to fetch all subuser_ids data. any help will really appreciable and helpfull.